# Why isn't mmap closing associated file (getting PermissionError: [WinError 32])?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, permissions, mmap

While experimenting with some of the code from the [Reading Binary Data into a Mutable Buffer](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch05.html#_solution_81) section of the O'Reilly website, I added a line at the end to remove the test file that was created.

However this always results in the following error:

`PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'data'`

I don't understand this behavior because the `with memory_map(test_filename) as m:` should implicitly close the associated file, but apparently doesn't. I can work around this by saving the file descriptor returned from `os.open()` and then explicitly closing it with an `os.close(fd)` after the block of statements in the `with` suite finishes.

**Is this a bug or have I missed something?**

Code (with the couple of commented-out lines showing my hacky workaround):

```
import os
import mmap

test_filename = 'data'

def memory_map(filename, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE):
#    global fd  # Save to allow closing.
    size = os.path.getsize(filename)
    fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDWR)
    return mmap.mmap(fd, size, access=access)

# Create test file.
size = 1000000
with open(test_filename, 'wb') as f:
     f.seek(size - 1)
     f.write(b'\x00')

# Read and modify mmapped file in-place.
with memory_map(test_filename) as m:
    print(len(m))
    print(m[0:10])
    # Reassign a slice.
    m[0:11] = b'Hello World'

# os.close(fd)  # Explicitly close the file descriptor -- WHY?

# Verify that changes were made
print('reading back')
with open(test_filename, 'rb') as f:
     print(f.read(11))

# Delete test file.
# Causes PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
# because it is being used by another process: 'data'
os.remove(test_filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> ### close()
>
> Closes the mmap. Subsequent calls to other methods of the object will result in a ValueError exception being raised. This will not close the open file.

The memory mapping is independent of the file handle. You can use the file handle as a normal file futher on.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying this issue. Seems kind of obvious now in hindsight. `^_^`

Comment: mmap duplicates the File handle, which it keeps open for use with its `size` and `resize` methods. It's sometimes frustrating that mmap keeps the duplicated File handle open. Windows would allow deleting the underlying file for a read-only (not writable) mapped view -- but mmap couples closing the File handle to unmapping the view.

Comment: @eryksun: the duplicated file handle is handled internally in mmap correctly. I doubt one can delete a mapped file, since the contents is mapped by demand.

Comment: Deleting a file that's mapped read-only is possible, but it requires a delete-on-close open (or equivalently `NtDeleteFile`), which works because Windows filesystems only call `MmFlushImageSection` with an `MmFlushForWrite` check in this case instead of the full `MmFlushForDelete` check that gets used by `DeleteFile` (i.e. native `NtSetInformationFile`, `FileDispositionInformation`). In recent versions of Windows this is how cmd.exe deletes files, which is how I discovered this.

Comment: Since `resize` doesn't work for a read-only mapping, the only reason to keep the File handle open is for the `size` method, but knowing the underlying file size (not the mapped size) is fairly useless for a read-only mapping. So I think it might have been better to close the File handle for a read-only view and raise an exception for `size()` in this case just like what's already done for `resize` -- or at least provide an option to close the File handle.