# Why isn't context manager closing file descriptor?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, mmap, contextmanager

I'm trying to create a context manager that uses `mmap` which is itself is a context manager. Initially I had an dumb open file problem [Why isn't mmap closing associated file (getting PermissionError: [WinError 32])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083929/why-isnt-mmap-closing-associated-file-getting-permissionerror-winerror-32) and an answer quickly explained *why* it wasn't working as desired.

Given that information, I've attempted two different ways to correct the issue, but neither one has worked.

The first approach was to use the`contextlib`'s `@contextmanager` decorator:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os
import mmap

#contextmanager
def memory_map(filename, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE):
    size = os.path.getsize(filename)
    fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDWR)
    print('about to yield')
    with mmap.mmap(fd, size, access=access) as m:
        yield m
    print('in finally clause')
    os.close(fd)  # Close the associated file descriptor.

test_filename = 'data'

# First create the test file.
size = 1000000
with open(test_filename, 'wb') as f:
     f.seek(size - 1)
     f.write(b'\x00')

# Read and modify mmapped file in-place.
with memory_map(test_filename) as m:  # Causes AttributeError: __enter__
    print(len(m))
    print(m[0:10])
    # Reassign a slice.
    m[0:11] = b'Hello World'

# Verify that changes were made
print('reading back')
with open(test_filename, 'rb') as f:
     print(f.read(11))

# Delete test file.
# Causes:
# PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it
# is being used by another process: 'data'
os.remove(test_filename)
```

But it results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "memory_map.py", line 27, in <module>
    with memory_map(test_filename) as m:  # Causes AttributeError: __enter__
AttributeError: __enter__
```

In the next attempt I tried explicitly creating a context manager class:

```
import os
import mmap

class MemoryMap:
    def __init__(self, filename, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE):
        print('in MemoryMap.__init__')
        size = os.path.getsize(filename)
        self.fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDWR)
        self.mmap = mmap.mmap(self.fd, size, access=access)

    def __enter__(self):
        print('in MemoryMap.__enter__')
        return self.mmap

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print('in MemoryMap.__exit__')
        os.close(self.fd)  # Close the associated file descriptor.
        print('  file descriptor closed')


test_filename = 'data'

# First create the test file.
size = 1000000
with open(test_filename, 'wb') as f:
     f.seek(size - 1)
     f.write(b'\x00')

# Read and modify mmapped file in-place.
with MemoryMap(test_filename) as m:
    print(len(m))
    print(m[0:10])
    # Reassign a slice.
    m[0:11] = b'Hello World'

# Verify that changes were made
print('reading back')
with open(test_filename, 'rb') as f:
     print(f.read(11))

# Delete test file.
# Causes PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
# because it is being used by another process: 'data'
os.remove(test_filename)
```

This makes it further, but the `PermissionError` is back—which really confuses me because the file descriptor *was* closed in that version as you can see in the output produced:

```
in MemoryMap.__init__
in MemoryMap.__enter__
1000000
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
in MemoryMap.__exit__
  file descriptor closed
reading back
b'Hello World'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "memory_map2.py", line 47, in <module>
    os.remove(test_filename)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'data'
```

So it seems I'm stuck again. Any ideas on what's wrong (as well as how to fix it)? Also, in the event they can both be fixed, which one is better if you have an opinion?

**Solutions**

There was an error in both snippets. This first was a simple typographical error. The `contextmanger` decorator was commented out. Should have been:

```
@contextmanager  # Leading "#" changed to "@".
def memory_map(filename, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE):
    size = os.path.getsize(filename)
    fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDWR)
    ...
```

In the second it was because the `mmap` *itself* was not being closed in the `__exit__()` method, just the associated file descriptor. That never occurred to me because the exception raised was the same as in the first case.

```
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print('in MemoryMap.__exit__')
        self.mmap.close()  # ADDED.
        os.close(self.fd)  # Close the associated file descriptor.
        print('  file descriptor closed')
```

Comment: Will this help you? I did read only the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215462/file-handling-in-python-permissionerror-winerror-32-the-process-cannot-acce

Comment: `#contextmanager` is not `@contextmanager`.

Comment: Also, your "in finally clause" is not actually in a `finally` clause.

Comment: @ElisByberi: Thanks. I actually looked at the question, and while It's similar, didn't see how it applied—but based on the answer below, maybe not...

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, that's the problem with the first snippet. Must have messed it up copying and pasting from my previous question.

Comment: @user2357112: Also the `print('in finally clause')` is just a (harmless) leftover from other things I tried before asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of your second attempt, you need to close the memory mapped file:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    self.mm.close()
    print('in MemoryMap.__exit__')
    os.close(self.fd)  # Close the associated file descriptor.
    print('  file descriptor closed')
```

Comment: I'll accept this since you posted it as a formal answer...thanks. It along with a comment under my question have provided fixes for both versions. Guess I keep mixing-up the closing of the `mmap` object and the closing the file associated with it.

Comment: On Windows a file can not be accessed by more than 1 process. You need to close mmap object before file object. The answer is correct.